# Python 2.7 string format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, datetime, format

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
sentence = "{:%B %d %Y}".format(now=datetime.now)
```

If for some reason I have to use an import from keyword how would I format this in three lines like the example above? My exact question is I don't know how to use the format parameters in this case.

Comment: `sentence = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y")`

Comment: `format()` uses different arguments then `strftime()` - see http://strftime.org/ and https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @furas, `str.format` internally use `__format__` of the object; [`datetime.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__) which is equivalent to [`datetime.strformat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) for `datetime` object.

Comment: @falsetru I always use `strftime` so I forgot that I read about it on https://pyformat.info/#datetime :) and https://pyformat.info/#custom_1

Answer (score 1):

1. You need pass `datetime.now()`, not `datetime.now` method itself.
2. specify `now` in the format string to use the keyword argument. Or you can omit `now` if you pass the datetime object as a positional argument.

---

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> "{now:%B %d %Y}".format(now=datetime.now())  # keyword argument
'November 12 2016'

>>> "{:%B %d %Y}".format(datetime.now())  # positional argument
'November 12 2016'
>>> "{0:%B %d %Y}".format(datetime.now())  # positional argument + explicit 0 (first arg)
'November 12 2016'
```

Answer (score 1):

as furas commented above, this works:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> sentence = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y")
>>> print sentence
November 12 2016
>>>
```